# Acquiring Locks when updating a Redis key/value

Tags: locking, timeout, redis, servicestack

I'm using AcquireLock method from ServiceStack Redis when updating and getting the key/value like this:

```
public virtual void Set(string key, T entity)
{
    using (var client = ClientManager.GetClient())
    {
        using (client.AcquireLock(key + ":locked", DefaultLockingTimeout, DefaultLockExpire))
        {
            client.Set(key, entity);
        }
    }
}
```

I've extended AcqurieLock method to accept extra parameter for expiration of the lock key. So I'm wondering that if I need AcquireLock at all or not? My class uses AcquireLock in every operation like Get<>, GetAll<>, ExpireAt, SetAll<>, etc..

But this approach doesn't work everytime. For example, if the operating in the lock throws an exception, then the key remains locked. For this situation I've added DefaultLockExpire parameter to AcquireLock method to expire the "locked" key.

Is there any better solution, or when do we need acquiring locks like "lock" blocks in multi-thread programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As The Real Bill answer has said, you don't need locks for Redis itself. What the ServiceStack client offers in terms of locking is not for Redis, but for your application. In a C# application, you can lock things locally with `lock(obj)` so that something cannot happen concurrently (only one thread can access the locked section at a time), but that only works if you have one webserver. If you want to prevent something happening concurrently, you need a locking mechanism living outside of the webserver. Redis is a good fit for this.

We have a case where it is checked if a customer has a shopping cart already and if not, create it. Between checking and creating it, there's a time where another request could have also found out that cart doesn't exist and might also proceed to create one. That's a classical case for locking but a simple `lock` wouldn't work here as the request may have arrived from an entirely different web-server. So for this, we use the **ServiceStack Redis client** (with some abstraction) to lock using Redis and only allow one request at a time to enter the "create a cart" section.

So to answer your actual question: no, you don't need a lock for getting/setting values to Redis.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use locks for get/set operations. Redis will do those actions atomically, so there is no chance of it getting "changed underneath you" when setting or getting. I've built systems where hundreds of clients are updating/operating on values concurrently and never needed a lock to do those operations (especially an expire).

I don't know how Service Stack redis implements the locking it has so I can't say why it is failing. However, I'm not sure I'd trust it given there is no true locking needed on the Redis side for data operations. Redis is single-threaded so locking there doesn't make sense.

If you are doing complex operations where you get a value, operate on things based on it, then update it after a while and can't have the value change in the meantime I'd recommend reading and groking http://redis.io/topics/transactions to see if what you want is what Redis is good for, whether your code needs refactored to eliminate the problem, or at the least find a better way to do it.

For example, [SETNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) may be the route you need to get what you want, but without details I can't say it will work.

Comment: The ServiceStack Redis client uses SETNX to accomplish its locking. The locking is pretty much an abstraction build on top of the API that Redis exposes.

Comment: No need to make assumptions and not trust something you don't know about. You can read about [distributed locking with redis here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisLocks). It's for distributed application locking, it's not for locking redis.

Comment: I would not trust the method described for locking redis data. For the reasons why, take a look at the setnx documentation - specifically the discussion about locking. Using a data store as an app-level mechanism for locking when said data store doesn't directly support that but you instead have to workaround it should only be done if the language doesn't support the standard concurrency mechanisms such as locking. I dont trust it precisely because I know about using redis for application level locking.

Comment: It is **NOT** intended to lock redis data, it's for **only** for providing a **distributed locking** mechanism in your **application** that just happens to use Redis. Not that it matters but the implementation uses both SETNX and GETSET.

Comment: Mythz I understand what you are saying, I am just saying it isn't a good idea to use Redis in this fashion. And you are correct in that adding get and set to the underlying implementation doesn't matter as it doesn't solve the underlying problems with using Redis in this fashion. Have a good, in-depth read on the pages referenced and on concurrent programming to get a good understanding of why it isn't a good idea, this isn't the forum for discussing such details.

Comment: Thanks but I already know redis and am familiar with the operations in question. I don't think you understand the purpose of the APIs which **work as advertised**. Feel free to point specifically to something you don't understand or don't think works - otherwise your blanket *read the docs* is both not-helpful possibly shows lack of knowledge of its contents.

Comment: I understand the purpose of the APIs, I don't agree with them. This is as crucial of a difference as understanding the OP stating they are using them to *lock data* by wrapping data operations with them. I understand your desire to defend your project but you need to understand it isn't under attack. Particularly since you agreed that you wouldn't use those calls to lock data, which is what the OP said they are doing. At any rate, I don't see what this discussion is contributing the question so if you have any more arguments feel free to send them privately.

Comment: The point isn't if you agree with its existence or not. You've initially stated you don't trust it (without knowing anything about it) then after being told its only for **application-level distributed locking** replied: `not a good idea to use redis in this fashion` - without supplying any specific or concrete info as to why or what times it wont work for the purpose it was intended. Basically unless you know of a valid reason, you shouldn't be advising on things you don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

As @JulianR says, the locking in ServiceStack.Redis is **only for application-level distributed locks** (i.e. to replace using a DB or an empty `.lock` file on a distributed file system) and it only works against other ServiceStack.Redis clients in other process using the same key/API to acquire the lock.

You would never need to do this for normal Redis operations since they're all atomic. If you want to ensure a combination of redis operations happen atomically than you would [combine them within a Redis Transaction](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisTransactions) or alternatively you can [execute them within a server-side Lua script](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/#new-iredisclient-lua-apis) - both allow atomic execution of batch operations.